# popup on image map JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a popup if you select an area on an image map with plain JS.
I just started JS and used my code for a button before. In the image map this code isn't working. I just see the popup for a second and it disappears again.

Hope somebody can help me out.

HTML:

```
  <div>
      <!-- Image Map -->
      <img src="../images/image.png" usemap="#image-map" alt="x">
        <map name="image-map">
      <area id="areaOne" target="x" alt="" title="x" href="" coords="294,72,203,88,140,125,122,169,140,235,195,270,242,225,301,174,351,136,391,92,334,75" shape="poly">
      </map>        
  </div>

  <div id="popUpOne">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Etiam sed leo felis. Maecenas tincidunt orci id orci vulputate congue. 
    Aliquam in molestie tortor. Sed erat felis, tincidunt id commodo sit amet, 
    dignissim fringilla metus. Proin porta, justo eget sollicitudin hendrerit, 
    sapien ligula imperdiet erat, vel hendrerit odio quam ut mauris. 
    Etiam laoreet justo massa, ac pretium sem pharetra at. Nullam ut felis orci. 
    Duis faucibus mauris libero, at semper nulla finibus vitae. In ut ex justo.</p>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var areaOne = document.getElementById("areaOne");
var popupOne = document.getElementById("popupOne");
popupOne.style.display = "none";
areaOne.addEventListener("click", function(){
if (popupOne.style.display === "none") {
   popupOne.style.display = "block";
} else {
   popupOne.style.display = "none";
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to write much javasript to display popup. It is possible with just one line of javascript. and also without javascript. See my answer

```js
function ModalOpen(namee) {
  window.location.href=namee
}
```

```css
.modal-header {
padding: 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.modal-dialog{
      width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.modal-content{
  
  position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal-title {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: beige;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}



.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ModalOpen('#popup1')">Pop Up Open With Javascript</button>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay" >  
<div class="popup">
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                    
                     
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Etiam sed leo felis. Maecenas tincidunt orci id orci vulputate congue. 
Aliquam in molestie tortor. Sed erat felis, tincidunt id commodo sit amet, 
dignissim fringilla metus. Proin porta, justo eget sollicitudin hendrerit, 
sapien ligula imperdiet erat, vel hendrerit odio quam ut mauris. 
Etiam laoreet justo massa, ac pretium sem pharetra at. Nullam ut felis orci. 
Duis faucibus mauris libero, at semper nulla finibus vitae. In ut ex justo.</p>
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    
                     <a class="close btn btn-default" href="#">x</a>
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div> 
      </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <a href="#popup2">Pop Up open with out Javascript</a>
<div id="popup2" class="overlay" >  
<div class="popup">
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                    
                     
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Etiam sed leo felis. Maecenas tincidunt orci id orci vulputate congue. 
Aliquam in molestie tortor. Sed erat felis, tincidunt id commodo sit amet, 
dignissim fringilla metus. Proin porta, justo eget sollicitudin hendrerit, 
sapien ligula imperdiet erat, vel hendrerit odio quam ut mauris. 
Etiam laoreet justo massa, ac pretium sem pharetra at. Nullam ut felis orci. 
Duis faucibus mauris libero, at semper nulla finibus vitae. In ut ex justo.</p>
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    
                     <a class="close btn btn-default" href="#">x</a>
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div> 
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code... Perhaps you'd like to add some explanation of how it answers the question?